# Data modifies automatically in ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have two ArrayLists:

```
private ArrayList<MenuItemBean> newList= new ArrayList<MenuItemBean>();  
private ArrayList<MenuItemBean> newGroupList= new ArrayList<MenuItemBean>();
```

In one function I am adding data to one ArrayList:

```
public void setConfirmList(List<MenuItemBean> cList){
    newList.addAll(cList);
    listAdapter=new ListAdapter(context, newList);
    lv_item.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

Another function where I am just grouping data (increasing quantity if product is already exist) using for-loop and adding data to a second ArrayList. But my problem is as I increase quantity in ArrayList2, my quantity in ArrayList1 itself modifies. I know its because of same reference of objects. Can we change this behavior by any way.

private void groupList() {

```
    newGroupList.clear();

    ArrayList<MenuItemBean> mList= new ArrayList<MenuItemBean>();
    mList.addAll(newList);

    for (int i = 0; i < mList.size(); i++){
        String productId = mList.get(i).getProductId();
        if(newGroupList.size()==0){
            newGroupList.add(mList.get(i));
        }else{ 
            Boolean bool=false;
            for (int j = 0; j< newGroupList.size(); j++){
                if(productId.equalsIgnoreCase(newGroupList.get(j).getProductId())){
                    bool= true;
                    //                      MenuItemBean newObject = new MenuItemBean(); 
                    //                      BeanUtils.copyProperties(newObject, newGroupList.get(j));
                    MenuItemBean bean= newGroupList.get(j);
                    int quantity = Integer.parseInt(bean.getUserQuantity());
                    Double sellingPrice = Double.parseDouble(bean.getSellingPrice());
                    quantity = quantity + 1;
                    sellingPrice = sellingPrice * quantity;
                    bean.setUserQuantity(String.valueOf(quantity));
                    bean.setUserPrice(String.valueOf(sellingPrice));
                    newGroupList.set(j, bean);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!bool){
                newGroupList.add(mList.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    listAdapter=new ListAdapter(context, newGroupList);
    lv_item.setAdapter(listAdapter);
}
```

I also tried by making copy of ArrayList by using

```
ArrayList newGroupList= new ArrayList<MenuItem>(newList);
```

But no help it simple copies data but not the reference. I tried but do not get any example to implement this.

Comment: If you want a *copy* of the data in the original list then you need to copy the data.

Comment: dear newton, please read the question clearly first before down vote it.

it is clearly mention, that I do not want any copy of data. My problem is just that my data is automatically modifies while I make changes in another arraylist. If you do not want to help, let others do it. Please do not down vote it.

Comment: First of all, I didn't downvote it. Second of all, you say you don't want a copy, but you don't want to affect the underlying list--those are contradictory. If you don't make a copy, you have a single data source. Third of all, don't lecture me.

Comment: @DaveNewton +1. To the OP: You described what you wanted to do, and it involves making a copy of your data whether you want it to be that way or not. You can't have one copy that has 2 different values in 2 different places. That just makes no sense.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I take my words back.

Comment: I tried approach of copying it but as I make change in copied item then that item in origional arrraylist itself changes. See second last line in question.

Comment: Then the copy probably wasn't done correctly, what you did on the bottom won't do it.

Answer (score 0):

> But no help it simple copies data but not the reference.

You're right. By create new list and  add data item to new list it's not copy object memory. Both item in those list point to same memory address in heap. So when you modify data item in one of those list. This affects others data item too. for example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ObjectItem> datas = new ArrayList<ObjectItem>();
    ObjectItem obj1 = new ObjectItem();
    obj1.setId(1);
    datas.add(obj1);
    System.out.println("memory addrs for obj1:" + datas.get(0)); //memory addrs for obj1: 533e846f
    List<ObjectItem> other_datas = new ArrayList<ObjectItem>();
    other_datas.addAll(datas);
    System.out.println("memory addrs for obj1:" + other_datas.get(0));//memory addrs for obj1: 533e846f
}
```

If you want to solve your problem, let's make deep copy data. For example:

```
public class ObjectItem {

public ObjectItem(ObjectItem other) {
    this.id = other.getId();
}

private int id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

}

And then using it

```
List<ObjectItem> new_datas = new ArrayList<ObjectItem>();
for (int i = 0; i < datas.size(); i++) {
    new_datas.add(new ObjectItem(datas.get(i)));
}
```